# Angular 8 Guards from link url or from browser url

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, canactivate

Is there any way to detect if someone tries to click a link on the already opened site or try to enter for first time the site from canActivate guard?

Comment: you can store some data when someone enter web page protected by canActivate may be using localstorage or sessionStorage and then on second time you can get that data to know.

Answer (score 0):

Angular app is **Single Page Application** it means it works on user browser. I think, but I'm not shure, if you protect for example admin route by guard and it's lazy loaded, user might not be able to download that part of code. But im not 100% sure about that, and I am preaty shure about that experienced hacker still will easly download all files. Buisness logic is good to not implement in Angular application.